# shieldui date picker not display in aspx

Tags: jquery, datepicker, shieldui

i trt this shieldui datepicker when i try this in html page this work fine but when i try this .aspx datepicker not display only textbox is visible..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#fromdate").shieldDatePicker({
            events: {
                change: function (e) {
                    var date = new Date(e.target.value());
                    var day = date.getDate();
                    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
                    var year = date.getFullYear();

                   // alert("The Date is :" + day + "/" + monthIndex + "/" + year);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $("#fromdate").swidget().value(); // return null

    $("#fromdate").swidget().value(new Date) // select the current date

    $("#fromdate").swidget().value(); // return current selected date

</script>

<input id="fromdate" runat="server" /><br /><br />
```

same code for .aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any error? What is the generated markup shown in the browser?

Also, probably you should reference the **fromdate** `<input>` like this:

```
$("#<%= fromdata.CliendID %>").shieldDatePicker(...)
```